# /bin/sh: test.sh:Command not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos7

A program is trying to execute some shell scripts. But unfortunately it gives out `command not found`

Path variables have already been set in `/etc/profile` and if you type the command in the shell, it will be executed as well.

But for some reason when this program tries to execute the thing via shell, it doesn't seem to find the environment paths/shell scripts.

Comment: Can you please provide the piece of code that leads to this error.

Comment: actually its a program trying to execute it command via shell.Program is a render farm manager

Comment: before the problematic command is executed, try issuing `export PATH`, assuming you have inspected the PATH value and **are sure** that the required directory is included. If you have compiled code that is calling a shell to execute some other commands, it's environment is not exactly the same as your terminal environment. `export`(ing) `PATH` may relieve the problem. You may also need to add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` too. Good luck.

Comment: how do i check the environment in which the program is running?

Comment: @PP_4321 At least in what language is this program written?

Comment: I bet the path has a literal tilde in it, so therefore it works from bash but not from sh. Either that or is not exported.

Comment: Try to put the full path to shell script.

Comment: @PP_4321 : Copy and paste the full error message. From your question, we can not infer which shell tried to run the command.

Answer (score 1):

**command not found** means either of these two is missing

1. Make you script executable

```sh
   chmod +x test.sh
```

2. Ensure its on the path

```sh
    export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/test.sh/
```

Comment: Technically if the file does not have the execute bit set and you attempt to invoke it as an executable, you get "Permission denied".

Comment: the same program runs these scripts with no problems in other system

Comment: *... with no problems in other system*. So maybe your shell is broken? No, not likely. try running `set > $HOSTNAME.env` on both machines and then diff the files. You should find something missing in one `env` file that affects your problem. Good luck.

Comment: They are similar other than user name difference, its quite similar. Is there some reason a program can run without this profile environments?

Answer (score -1):

Try running the file with `./test.sh`. It solved the issue at my end.